# Ошибка cli::array<unsigned char, 1> ^" в "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>

Tags: c++-cli

error Ошибка cli::array<unsigned char, 1> ^" в "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>

Comment: @user7860670  - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11798/184217

Comment: @αλεχολυτ - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11798/184217

Comment: [c++cli] подразумевает [c++]. Многим (в том числе мне), не интересно первое, в отличии от второго. Так что я за удаление левой метки

Comment: по самому вопросу - json хранит текстовые данные, а туда пытаются всунуть бинарные данные. Даже если туда его затолкать, ничем хорошим это не закончится. Преобразовывайте в текстовое представление (например, base64) и если угадаете с функцией, то все сразу и взлетит.

Comment: @KoVadim - а при чём тут ваш личный интерес? Метка языка C++ может соседствовать со многими метками. Например, sql, json, unreal-engine. И если что-то вам не нравится, то всё, метку C++ ставить нельзя?

Comment: может. и на мете уже Вам объяснили.